# Volumetric Bullet Trails?

Tags: shaders, volumetrics, shader-nodes

I'm trying to create a volumetric bullet trail for a stylistic piece. I'm struggling with how to continue with what I have, which basically amounts to stretching out a glowing noise volume. I assume there's a better way to go about this but I'm unsure. Does anyone with more volumetrics knowledge have any help for me?

I'm trying to go for the trailing go (without an actual bullet inside so it can be re-used for energy projectiles and the like) similar to this stock image I found.

[image]

Really, I just need ways to actually *shape* volumes. I know there's some really crazy stuff you can do with them and I want to help bring out more of that.

Answer (score 2):

I got this effect by applying a bunch of noise textures to a trail shape, animating it by using `#frame` in the Mapping node X location, added particles at high velocity emitting from the bullet. and so on. My effect is more like 2.5D not a 3D volume necessarily, but the principles are nearly identical. You would just make sure you use 3 or 4D noises and apply it to a volume.

Final Result

[image]

Meshes

[image]

Bullet Material

[image]

Flame Material

[image]

Flame Object Modifiers

[image]

Flame Object Displace Texture Settings

[image]

Particle Material (Though i don't think this did much, i didn't bother much with it)

[image]

Comment: that's a very neat result :) reminds me of a shuttle re-entering atmosphere :))